# same column value output as percentage in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation

Sample Table:

[image]

Here table has 5 entries for employee 1. 1 means present, 2 means absent and 3 means late. I want following output.

sample Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty simple way:

```
select employee_id,
       avg( present_id = 1 ) as present_ratio,
       avg( present_id = 2 ) as absent_ratio,
       avg( present_id = 3 ) as late_ratio
from t
group by employee_id;
```

This produces the value as a number between 0 and 1.  You can multiply by 100 if you really want a percentage; I find the ratio easier to understand to to work with.

This uses a MySQL extension where the result of a boolean expression is treated as a number in a numeric context, with 0 for false and 1 for true.  A more verbose method uses ANSI-standard functionality:

```
avg(case when present_id = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) as present_ratio
```

Comment: it doesn't fulfill what I wanted. present_ratio+absent_ratio+ late_ratio should be hundred. but it gives different result.this is why I gave sample output. here just I gave only one employee's entry. there will be many employees.

Comment: @hmamun . . . It adds up to "1", not "100".  If you want 100, then multiply by 100 as I explain in the answer.  This query is per employee as implied by your question (your result set has a column for the employee id).